# Will the descriptors closed after fork be invalid in the other process?

Tags: c, sockets

I'm referring the below code snippet from this [link](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/C_C++/socket.htm):

```
while (1)
 {
   newsockfd = accept(sockfd,
               (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
   if (newsockfd < 0)
     error("ERROR on accept");
   pid = fork();
   if (pid < 0)
     error("ERROR on fork");
   if (pid == 0)
   {
     close(sockfd);
     dostuff(newsockfd);
     exit(0);
   }
   else
     close(newsockfd);
 } /* end of while */

void dostuff (int sock)
{
   int n;
   char buffer[256];

   bzero(buffer,256);
   n = read(sock,buffer,255);
   if (n < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket");
   printf("Here is the message: %s\n",buffer);
   n = write(sock,"I got your message",18);
   if (n < 0) error("ERROR writing to socket");
}
```

After the fork() call, there would be two processes - Parent and child.

For the parent process, the else part holds true, and so it will close newsockfd. But newsockfd is used by child process for read and write system calls in dostuff method. Won't the read and write system calls fail in this case?

Comment: The child should not call `exit(0)` but should call `_exit(0)`. Otherwise, you flush any streams that existed at the call to `fork` twice. It won't matter in this example, but set a good example for more realistic cases.

Comment: Once the `fork()` returns, the two processes are separate; they have separate copies of the descriptors, pointing at the same open file description.  The close in one process does not affect the other at all (beyond, perhaps, making the other process the sole owner of the open file description).  See [POSIX `open()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/openat.html) for the distinction between file descriptor and open file description; also `dup2()`, `fork()`, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, because during `fork` all open file descriptors are copied and they are not the same descriptors, they just point to the same file.

From the [`fork(2)` manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork):

> The child inherits copies of the parent's set of open file
>   descriptors. Each file descriptor in the child refers to the same open
>   file description (see open(2)) as the corresponding file descriptor in
>   the parent. This means that the two descriptors share open file status
>   flags, current file offset, and signal-driven I/O attributes (see the
>   description of F_SETOWN and F_SETSIG in fcntl(2)).

Comment: A `close` only shuts down a communication endpoint if it closes the last reference to that endpoint. In this case, the other process also holds a reference to that endpoint. So the `close` only releases that process' reference.

Comment: Agreed that the child process will have a copy of newsockfd. But newsockfd in both parent and child processes would be pointing to the same client socket. So the parent process would be closing it down. Am I missing something here?

Comment: You missed, what David Schwartz said - `close` shuts down a communication endpoint if it closes the last reference to that endpoint. If any other reference (the other descriptor) exists, the endpoint itself won't be closed.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot David and Rafal for the quick reply.

Comment: I see that the parent process closes a copy of its client socket FD and goes on to accept for the next connection. But for the client endpoint to be completely closed, is it not required for dostuff to call close(sock) before exiting the function?

Comment: The descriptor is closed after terminating the execution with `exit(0)`. I must admit, that it is not the best idea, but makes the example simple (probably too simple).

Answer (score 2):

The child process will have its own brand new 'newsockfd' in its own memory. The socket handle there will have nothing in common with the parent's 'newsockfd' which is being closed.

Comment: Up until the point of closure, the two sets of file descriptors share the same open file descriptions (so they have that in common; also the same numbers in each process), but you're right that the closure of a file in one process has no effect on the corresponding file descriptor in the other process.